# Append values in matrix python

Tags: python-3.x, matrix, append

I am trying to populate values of a i x j matrix, where each cell will have to values assigned to it [  ,  ].

I have tried many things. For example, the first cell I have tried

```
F[0][0]=[None,0]
```

and

```
F[0][0].append=[None,0]
```

and

```
F[0][0].append(None,0)
```

However the cells are still []. I'm assuming I must be making a stupid mistake, but if you can please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to work with initialized embeded lists, I guess you could use this:

```
F = [[None]*3]*2 # initializes your 2 lines and 3 colomns list, if needed
>> [[None, None, None], [None, None, None]]

F[1] = [0,None,2,3] # fills your second line (embeded list 1)
>> [[None, None, None], [0, None, 2, 3]]

F[0] = [5] # erases and changes your first line (embeded list 0)
>> [[5], [0, None, 2, 3]]

F.append([1,-1,None]) # adds a new list (which will be the embeded list 2)
>> [[5], [0, None, 2, 3], [1, -1, None]]
```

Given your post it seems that it covers what you are trying to achieve. Mind that if you primary defines your list by `F=[[]]`, you will only have access to `F[0]` and to add another embeded list you will need to use list.append.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up figuring it out, but this was sort of what I ended up doing, thanks! Someone told me I needed to add "nones" to initialize the matrix(before I filled them with other values), which I was not doing.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason not to use `numpy.array` in your code ? Your could initialize your (i,j) matrix (let's say i=2 and j=3 for instance) like that:

```
import numpy as np
F = np.zeros((2,3)) # initializes the matrix (fill it with 0)
```

Then if you want to fill for instance its first row (be carreful python indexes start at 0):

```
F[0,:] = [2,None,6]
>> array([[ 2., nan,  6.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

It is always better for speed to correctly initialize your matrix, but would you need to add a row you can also yse `numpy.append` method ([numpy.append](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.append.html)):

```
np.append(F,[[5,-1,3]],axis=0) # axis=0 specifies that you want to add a row
>> array([[ 2., nan,  6.],
   [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
   [ 5., -1.,  3.]])
```

For vectors and matrices, `numpy` is much more convenient that embeded lists.

Comment: Yes, I was originally using numpy, but was told it would not work for this. Embedded lists is the data structure I need for this program.

Comment: Could you elaborate which kind of data you use, that makes `numpy` no fit ?